# Get index from subset in R

Tags: r

I would like to access the row index of a subset of a data frame in R, but I have not been able to find a way to access the information. For example, if I had the data frame:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
c <- data.frame(a, b)
```

And I grab the second row:

```
d <- c[2,]
```

If I print `d` I get:

```
print(d)
  a b
2 2 3
```

So I assume that R somehow stores the row that `d` was in the original data frame! But if I go:

```
str(d)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num 2
 $ b: num 3
```

I can't see where that `2`(for the row) is stored. Is there a way to access that value?

And yes, I am aware that in this example I already have the row number from subsetting. However, most of the time I am subsetting logically, and in any case I would like to avoid separately finding the row index and also passing it to a function.

Comment: `rownames(d)` should work. Note that the return is always `character`, so in some (extreme) examples, `dat[1,]` and `dat["1",]` might return different results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
c <- data.frame(a, b)
d <- c[2,]
rownames(d) # "2"; class(rownames(d)) = "character"
as.numeric(rownames(d)) # 2; class(as.numeric(rownames(d))) = "numeric"
```

Comment: Thanks, I never realized that the row index is automatically stored as the row name!